# android database not working in multiple activities

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-activity

I have a DatabaseHelper class and DatabaseAdapter class. When i try to select data from several activities, i get empty database. What am i doing wrong? I am reading or writing to dabase while calling database adapter and passing current activity as context.

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MySampleDatabase";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 15;
    private final Context context;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        AssetManager manager = context.getResources().getAssets();
        InputStream is;
        try {
            is = manager.open("SQLStatements");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            String line;
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                sb.append(line);
            }
            String[] queries = (new String(sb)).split(";");
            is.close();
            for(int i = 0; i < queries.length; i++){
                db.execSQL(queries[i]);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS UserDrugs");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS UserDrugsUsages");
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
public class DatabaseUserDrugsUsagesAdapter {
    public static final String KEY_USER_DRUG_ID = "UserDrugID";
    public static final String KEY_PACKAGE_ID = "PackageID";
    public static final String KEY_TIME_TO_USE = "TimeToUse";
    public static final String KEY_USED = "Used";
    public static final String KEY_PACKAGE_NAME = "PackageName";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "UserDrugsUsages";
    private Context context;
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private DatabaseHelper dbHelper;

    public DatabaseUserDrugsUsagesAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public DatabaseUserDrugsUsagesAdapter open() throws SQLException {
        dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        dbHelper.close();
    }

    public void clearDatabaseTable(){
        database.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE);
    }

    public Cursor selectUserDrugUsagesByDate(String date){
        return database.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
                KEY_USER_DRUG_ID,
                KEY_PACKAGE_ID,
                KEY_TIME_TO_USE,
                KEY_USED,
                KEY_PACKAGE_NAME}, "TimeToUse like '" + date + "%'", null, null, null, null);
    }

    public long writeUserDrugUsage(int userDrugId, int packageId, String timeToUse, boolean used, String packageName) {
        ContentValues initialValues = createContentValues(userDrugId, packageId, timeToUse, used, packageName);

        return database.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }

    private ContentValues createContentValues(int userDrugId, int packageId, String timeToUse, boolean used, 
            String packageName) {

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_USER_DRUG_ID, userDrugId);
        values.put(KEY_PACKAGE_ID, packageId);
        values.put(KEY_TIME_TO_USE, timeToUse);
        values.put(KEY_USED, used);
        values.put(KEY_PACKAGE_NAME, packageName);

        return values;
    }
}
```

EDIT:
There is the code where i call select function.

```
Cursor c = null;
String name = null;
DatabaseUserDrugsUsagesAdapter db = new DatabaseUserDrugsUsagesAdapter(context);
db.open();
c = db.selectDrugNameById(id);
db.close();

if(c != null && c.getCount() > 0){
    c.moveToFirst();
    name = c.getString(4);
}
c.close();
```

Comment: It's not clear... are you saying the database is never created, or that the cursor returned when you try a query is empty?

Comment: When i select data from second Activity, i get empty cursor. When i work with first activity, where i insert data to database, it works perfectly.

Comment: Hmm, nothing looks amiss with your query.  First thing other than that to come to mind is that your date formats don't match.  Post the class where you make the query.  Oh, and how are you determining that you are getting nothing from the query?

Comment: I checked that several times and my date formats match, it's not the problem. I determine that i get nothin by the fact, that i get an empty Cursor. The Cursor is empty even if i select everything from table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are you closed your database before manipulating the cursor.

**Actually Cursor is like a list/pointer created from a database resource.**

I changed your code and it will work just fine give it a try

```
Cursor c = null;
String name = null;
DatabaseUserDrugsUsagesAdapter db = new DatabaseUserDrugsUsagesAdapter(context);
db.open();
c = db.selectDrugNameById(id);

if(c != null && c.getCount() > 0){
     c.moveToFirst();
     name = c.getString(4);
        }
    c.close();
    db.close();
```